# How to add a flash game on electron

Tags: javascript, flash, electron, frontend

I have an electron app and I want to put an SWF(flash) file on it.
I have the direct link to it but I do not know how to download it and how to put on my electron app.
link: http://www.coolmath-games.com/gameFrame?u=sites/cmatgame/files/games/bouncing.swf&f=bouncing.swf
as an important point my app should be offline, of course, I have poor experienced with flash game. My target is to run the bouncing ball game on my app.

Comment: Do you own the flash game? Is it open source?

Answer (score 0):

just pressed the padlock icon in the inquiry or the html link it will allow you to find the flash on any browsing app turn in to allow to activate it